# Android Studio 1.0 Gradle project sync failed

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I've just downloaded and installed Android Studio 1.0; having previously removed the beta version and deleted all Android Studio and gradle-related folders from my user folder.

I have created a new project using the wizard, but am getting "*Gradle project sync failed*".

I've seen references to the Maven repository elsewhere, but don't know if that applies here.

---

An extract from the log is below, oh and I'm running on Windows 7.

```
2014-12-11 19:02:59,863 [ 398801]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38 
2014-12-11 19:02:59,867 [ 398805]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38 
2014-12-11 19:02:59,869 [ 398807]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2014-12-11 19:02:59,871 [ 398809]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\IANMAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo2717331004078521426.gradle] 
2014-12-11 19:03:02,767 [ 401705]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2014-12-11 19:03:02,802 [ 401740]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2014-12-11 19:03:02,941 [ 401879]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 3 ms 
2014-12-11 19:03:02,941 [ 401879]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to update 
2014-12-11 19:03:02,941 [ 401879]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 0 ms
```

---

Any ideas??

Comment: What do you get in the Gradle console?

Comment: The Gradle console is empty